# sudo apt update NO_PUBKEY error on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Im running Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) on a Raspberry Pi 4 and trying a project, https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-internet-speed-monitor/ , where it runs a speedtest and logs the result. I just finished the "Writing our Speed Test Python Script" section and i am trying to update with sudo apt update, but i get this error. [picture of apt update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmZgu.png)

I'm super new to linux, and have no idea why it would be updating from ookla.com. The only reason i can think of why its updating from ookla is that i installed `sudo pip3 install speedtest-cli`, but im really not sure. When i go to the repository it says it's pulling from, [https://ookla.bintray.com/debian buster Release](https://ookla.bintray.com/debian%20buster%20Release) it says Repository path missing or not specified.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suitable for [raspberrypi.se] instead.

Comment: btw, when asking a question on SO, always including the raw text of the output, not just a picture, makes it a lot easier to debug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Run this:**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
```

> The apt packaging system has a set of trusted keys that determine whether a package can be authenticated and therefore trusted to be installed on the system.
>
> Sometimes the system does not have all the keys it needs and runs into this issue.

Comment: Hello, I tried to install speedtest cli with install procedure found on Ooka [website](http://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli#ubuntu) but I have an issue like what the public key is not available for targeted release(no matter the targeted bionic/xenial/jessie/etc.) 
`GPG error: https://ookla.bintray.com/debian jessie Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 379CE192D401AB61 `